# Hydraulic press

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

Let's say I have an asymmetrical U-shaped tube, one branch is wider than the other. If I now pour some liquid into this tube, the liquid reach the same high in both branches. Then, I will cover both branches with pistons. This configuration is static, there no movement of the liquid anywhere. However, If I now push the piston of the narrow brach, the liquid starts moving and the situation isn't static anymore. In addition, due to Pascal's principle, the larger piston won't be moving as result of the force $F$ I have applied on the smaller piston, but it will be moving due to the force  $\eta F$. My question is, in this dynamic configuration, when the pistons stop moving, and why?

Note:
Let's assume there is no friction of any kind between the piston and the tube.

Comment: That depends more on the specifics of "I now push the piston" than it does on the details of the pistons and tubes.

Comment: Like for example I am managing to push the piston with a constant force F with my finger

Comment: Is the U tube closed or open?  If closed, how do you pour liquid into one side?  Which side are you pouring liquid into?  Where do the pistons enter the problem?  More detail and a picture would be very helpful.

Comment: @DavidWhite after I poured the liquid I covered both branches with pistons, then I pushed the smaller piston with a constant force F.

Answer (score 0):

If you push the smallerpiston with constant force, the other piston moves with a greater force a smaller distance, if you stop moving one piston the other will stop too.

Comment: If i removed the force, why wouldn't the liquid come back to its initial configuration?

Comment: You are right, I supposed you keep the force and just stop moving. otherwise you get a damped harmonic oscillation.

Comment: But how, keeping the force, could you stop the movement?

Comment: you start pushing down , in the beginning you need a small force, but as the fluid gets higher on the other side your force will have to increase,  So after a few cm you stop and hold the piston with the last force you applied, than the movement will stop.  If you just release your piston  you will have a damped oscillation. Or you say more exactly what your experiment is. You mentioned yourself that it is a model of a hydraulic press (but only if you have something to press at the opposing side.)Otherwise you have a hydraulic lifting platform.